# Router implementing with Navigation Architecture Component in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, fragment, router, android-architecture-navigation

I want implement router like in the code below, but in this case I should pass fragment or activity through ViewModel, but [guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#build-ui) says

> The ViewModel doesn't know about UI components

How I can resolve this problem?

```
class RouterImpl : Router {

    override fun openItem(fragment: Fragment, item: Item) {
        val action = ItemListFragmentDirections.actionNavigationItemToInfoFragment(item)
        findNavController(fragment).navigate(action)
    }
}
```

```
class ItemListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val router: Router
) : ViewModel() {

    fun openItem(fragment: Fragment, item: Item) = router.openItem(fragment, item)
}
```

Comment: Hi; questions about best practices are off-topic at Stack Overflow as they're primarily opinion-based. If possible, rephrase your question to ask something measurable and objective; perhaps if you have *specific* concerns about something...

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the VIPER architecture, you'll notice that the Router is tied to the Presenter, which, effectively is Activity/Fragment.

If you still try to combine the MVVM with the VIPER pattern, I'd suggest you take a different approach and try with the DI - Dependency inversion. This way the MVVM will know only about the abstraction of an entity (interface) that is able to perform the routing procedure (traverse fragments).

However, this is a slippery slope, since you're still able to create dependency between the ViewModel and Activity/Fragment and, thus, lead you to the memory leak.

Much safer way would be to implement some sort of observer in the Router (eg. live data observer), which will do exactly what you want in a safe (async) manner.